# Why isn't this login page detecting a correct password?

Tags: php, authentication, admin

I am making a PHP login admin.  I've followed two tutorials on Youtube, and all the comments say that this works.  But it doesn't work for me.

If I enter a wrong password, then I get "wrong username and password" as expected.  But if I enter the correct password, I also get "wrong username and password".  The connection to the database seems to be OK.

index.htm (main login):

---

```
<form method="POST" action="checklogin.php" name="form1">

<label for="username" class="label">Username:</label><input class="inputstyle2w" type="text" name="username">

<br>

<label for="password" class="label">Password:</label><input class="inputstyle22" type="password" name="password">   
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">

</form>
```

---

This is the checklogin.php:

```
<?
$host = "cpanel1";
$username = "trekking_test";
$password = "testtest";
$db_name = "trekking_test";
$tbl_name = "members";

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die (mysql_error_db());

$myusername = $_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword = $_POST['mypassword'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1) {
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword");
    header("location:control.php");
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        }

?>
```

---

And finally the adminpage (control.php):

```
<?
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)) {
    header("location:index.htm");
}
?>


<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge; chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Tower 2.0 vefumsjónarkerfi">
        <meta name="author" content="Nicejob">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/adminstyle.css">

        <title>Tower 2.0 - you update your website by yourself!</title>

    </head>

    <body>
blah blah - you are not suppost to see this unless you are logged in
    </body>     

</html>
```

Comment: I not good at this.... all the HTML PHP code dissappeard when I posted my question.... guess I did something wrong when entering codes

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but some things you will need: 1. You need to `die()` after doing a `header()`, otherwise the following data will be output anyway.

Comment: You have an SQL injection vulnerability there. Make sure to sanitize any data you get from user input

Comment: i fixed it for u. also  accept some previous answers to ur previous questions

Comment: 2. your code is vulnerable to SQL injection: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php you need to fix that before going live.

Comment: @Ingþór When you're posting code. Select the code block and hit CTRL+K or click on those curly braces in the editor to make it format the code.

Comment: Yes, please accept answers to your questions.  That's the whole point of this site, to ask questions, get answers, and let everyone know which one is right so people in the future don't have to guess.

Comment: good luck on this..  
if you're planning to feed your query user submitted values with no sanitizing at all, you might as well put a gun to your head and ask the first who passes by to pull the trigger for you..

Comment: A good tutorial to look at: http://www.evolt.org/PHP-Login-System-with-Admin-Features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this is fine:

```
$host = "cpanel1";
$username = "trekking_test";
$password = "testtest";
$db_name = "trekking_test";
```

You don't need this, it's going to make your SQL confusing to read

```
$tbl_name = "members";
```

That's fine.

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die (mysql_error_db());
```

No no bad. Always escape user input data ***EDIT*** and your form names don't match:

```
$myusername = $_POST['username'];
$mypassword = $_POST['password'];
```

This should be:

```
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

You don't need all the columns since you're just checking the count, and `mypassword` is not in the correct format

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='mypassword'";
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT `username` FROM `members` WHERE `username`='$myusername' and `password`='$mypassword'";
```

You're assuming the query succeeded. You should always handle the case that it doesn't:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result) {
   // Let the user know something went wrong
}
```

`session_register` is going to confuse people unfamiliar with the traditional `$_SESSION['name'] = 'value'` syntax, use the more traditional form instead. You just want to know they logged in, and `session_start()` hasn't been called:

```
if($count==1) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    // The correct format is "Location: control.php"
    header("Location: control.php");
    exit; //Always exit after sending Location headers
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

Then on your page:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    // Once again, Location: 
    header("Location: index.htm");
    exit; // exit after redirect
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't your inputs be named 'myusername' and 'mypassword'?  That's what you're looking for with your $_POST['myusername'];...

I would bet if you echo $myusername and $mypassword just after you set them in the PHP you'll find they're empty, because you're not posting 'myusername', just 'username'.

Comment: Yes, I spotted that error and I´ve fix it now and it seems to be its working :)

Comment: Just click the checkmark next to the answer that's right on this (and your previous) questions.  :)

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the "$" before "mypassword" in your SQL query.

And your HTML form input fields are called "username" and "password", but you are looking for "myusername" and "mypassword" in the $_POST array.

Also read up on SQL injection.  Your code is vulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your question.  This is why YouTube tutorials are not the perfect learning medium.

1. You need to sanitize your input to prevent SQL Injection.  Check out [the link Pekka posted in the comments](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) for good info on what you're guarding against.  The function you'll want for MySQL is [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), but remember you can't call that until you have connected to the database, so keep that in mind.
2. Passwords should **never** be stored as plain text.  The best thing to do is to use a one-way hashing algorithm.  This has two of its own caveats, of course:

   a. Make sure you choose an appropriate algorithm.  `MD5` and `SHA1` are **not** appropriate.  Some methods to look up are `Eksblowfish` (also known as `bcrypt`, not to be confused with `blowfish`, a 2-way encryption block cipher), `Tiger`, `SHA-256`, `SHA-512` and `Whirlpool`

   b. You may think this is going overboard for your purposes, but the more you practice best *practices* the more natural they will become for you, and the better programmer you will be.  You should use a rotating salt called a *nonce* to make the passwords more secure.  A salt is a string added to a password before it is encrypted or hashed, so that `pass_hash_actual = hash_function(salt + password)`.

   - [**Shameless Blog Plug**](http://www.dereleased.com/2010/02/09/lets-talk-about-your-password-model/): This article will tell you about specific implementation in PHP for bcrypt, but I'm primarily linking it for the articles to which it links, which will give you a great overview of how and why to use a nonce with your passwords.

I was going to write up an implementation guide here, but onteria_'s guide gives you everything you need in that department, [so make sure you read it thoroughly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063068/php-admin-login-curse/6063214#6063214).  Happy coding!

Comment: It works now.... but I noticed the url should be encrypted right?

it´s very scary it redirects and the path is just admin.php ...thanx for the link, Im gonna check it out

Answer (score 1):

Well for one thing [`session_is_registered`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-is-registered.php) is depreciated

Do this instead:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){...}
```

also add somwhere to output mysql errors, like:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple rows in the table that match the query? Since you are using:

```
if($count==1) {
```

you will get the failure message if two or more matches are found.

Comment: The problem is, if we're using `username` to check for login details, it MUST be unique. With this in mind, `$count` MUST by equal to 1 or 0, and you should get an error when it's not, because that means you have bad data you need to cleanup. Of course, if you have a UNIQUE index like you should, then this will be caught much earlier.

Comment: The talbe look like this


ID   USERNAME   PASSWORD
-------------------------
1    hulemo     kurbitur
2    ingthor    1234

Answer (score 1):

```
if($count>0) {
```

The query will return a result set with a single row if the login details are correct and zero rows if the login details are incorrect. Use `mysql_num_rows` to find out the number of rows in the result set and hence determine whether the login details were correct or not.